# Doxygen : Display warning for undocumented method

Tags: documentation, warnings, doxygen

i've activated warnings with doxygen

```
WARNINGS              = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED  = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR     = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC      = YES
```

But undocumented methods like this one:

```
void AnimationManager::setAnimationTimeStep( double timeStep )
{
  ...
}
```

Do not throw any warning during doxygen generation.
Is there any way to display warning in this situation ?

Same problem with undocumented return , for example

```
/**
 * @brief brief description
 */
bool AnimationManager::hasAnimationTimeStep( )
{
  ...
}
```

Does not throw warning for undocumented return

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure the files containing the undocumented code are within the scope of your INPUT definition?

Comment: yes, absolutely, these methods throw errors if i documentating them but forget a parameter for example. But i understand i am *suposed* to have warning ? i may try some minimal test here.

Comment: Are you using EXTRACT_ALL? Is that is set YES it disables some warnings.

Comment: You're right, thanks you for pointing that out. setting it to NO produce warnings for undocumented methods.

Comment: Added as an "answer" for completeness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are missing warnings that you would otherwise expect, check whether `EXTRACT_ALL` is set to `YES`.

From the commented version of the doxyfile:

```
# Note: This will also disable the warnings about undocumented members that are
# normally produced when WARNINGS is set to YES.
```

Using `EXTRACT ALL` can be useful for a first pass or to extract something from a non-doxygenned source, but in general it's a good idea to aim to be able to turn this off and thus be able to get the warnings that refine the parts that you actually need documented.