# Make correct doxygen documentation a build requirement

Tags: doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document a C++ project which is becoming bigger and bigger and I have been wondering how I could make Doxygen a build requirement for the project. In other words, I would like my build process to fail and stop if any class/method/etc. has not been *successfully documented* for Doxygen. I use `make` for building.

For example, I would like this to fail (i.e. not build):

```cpp
/**
 * @bbrief Oops, tag does not exist, warning is issued and hence build fails.
 */
void f()
{
    // Do something...
}


/**
 * @brief Main function for program X
 *
 * @return End of execution status.
 *
 * ...
 *
 */
int main()
{
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

but this to build:

```cpp
/**
 * @brief Okay, this is fine.
 *
 */
void f()
{
    // Do something...
}


/**
 * @brief Main function for program X
 *
 * @return End of execution status.
 *
 * ...
 *
 */
int main()
{
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried searching the Internet for this kind of feature but so far have found nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609599/doxygen-display-warning-for-undocumented-method

Comment: @battlmonstr Interesting link, I will certainly activate those warning. But they are only warnings, they do not stop the building process. I have updated the question to reflect that a bit more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases the documentation is generated but due to the warnings it is incomplete. I see a few possibilities:

- For this purpose the configuration setting `WARN_AS_ERROR` is present (see: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_warn_as_error). Possible disadvantage is that process stopes directly when a warning is encountered.
- catch the warnings in a file and count them / see if the file is
  empty and based on this decide whether the build was successful or
  not.

**Edit**

As noted by @inkychris the `WARN_AS_ERROR` has, as of doxygen version 1.9.0, the possibility `FAIL_ON_WARNINGS`. From the documentation:

> WARN_AS_ERROR
>
> If the `WARN_AS_ERROR` tag is set to `YES` then doxygen will immediately stop when a warning is encountered. If the `WARN_AS_ERROR` tag is set to `FAIL_ON_WARNINGS` then doxygen will continue running as if `WARN_AS_ERROR` tag is set to NO, but at the end of the doxygen process doxygen will return
> with a non-zero status.
>
> Possible values are: `NO`, `YES` and `FAIL_ON_WARNINGS`.

Comment: Nice options. For the first option, do you know it Doxygen returns a specific error code or is it seen as a successful program run? In other words, is there a way for `make` to know that Doxygen stopped because it produced a warning, and not because it completed normal generation?

Comment: Normally doxygen returns 0, in case of an error it returns 1 (in case a sub-process is forked it might return on error a 127 as well)

Comment: As of doxygen v1.9, looks like `WARN_AS_ERROR` now also accepts a value of `FAIL_ON_WARNINGS` which will let doxygen run through but return non-zero status code.

Comment: @inkychris thanks, indeed I've updated the answer so this new possibility ((from December 27m, 2020) is shown as well.